# Android Intent and startActivity in Libgdx (non Activity or AndroidApplication class)

Tags: android, android-intent, libgdx

Please help me how to run the below code in Libgdx thread - in render(),create(),etc...

```
public class MyGame implements ApplicationListener, InputProcessor {
...
Intent discoverableIntent = new
Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
startActivity(discoverableIntent);
.....
Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(
"http://market.android.com/details?id=" + getPackageName()));
startActivity(marketIntent);
```

The code has compilation errors.
I googled some similar threads, but no exact code examples with "startActivity".
Thanks.

Comment: "startActivity" word is red in IntelliJ. Compilation is okay for "extends Activity or AndroidApplication" class

Comment: Cannot resolve method "startActivity". Compilation is okay for "extends Activity or AndroidApplication" class

Answer (score 16):

LibGDX is a platform independent library, so all the code that uses the LibGDX platform netural APIs must itself be platform independent (so no Android, or Windows calls, etc).  To access platform-specific features, the standard way is to define an interface, and use the interface from your platform-neutral code.  Then create an implementation of the interface in the Android (or Desktop) specific projects for your application, and pass that implementation when you initialize your libGDX component.

This tutorial has more details: http://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/IntegratingAndroidNativeUiElements3TierProjectSetup

Here's another description of the same approach (its better written, but the example isn't as clearly relevant to you): https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code

The tutorial is interested in accessing Android native UI elements, but the basic idea is the same as what you want.

Comment: Thanks. I added second example to my code.But how to run the example's method "submitScore"? It should be static to run from Libgdx thread. But I have "startActivity" in this method, which gives compilation error if "submitScore" changed to static.

Comment: In first example I don't understand what negation symbol "!" means in names. Such as "import android.app.!AlertDialog;". Or class name "!ActionResolverAndroid". It causes compilation errors.

Comment: I added first example to my project. I have compilation error that class ActionResolverAndroid should be abstract. If I make it abstract, I have error in Activity on line "actionResolver = new ActionResolverAndroid(this);". Dead end

Comment: I found one more tutorial: http://tortillacode.wordpress.com/2011/08/03/launch-android-intents-from-within-libgdx/
But it does not work too. It is not clear understandable to which file should I add the example's code

Comment: I could run second example. And I got compilation error: javac: invalid flag: path to Leaderboard file. I created the project again. The same flag error. I tryed to run my method as follows:      AndroidLeaderboard androidLeaderboard=new AndroidLeaderboard();
        androidLeaderboard.submitScore("aaa",0);

Comment: @nms For second example, `submitScore` method must not be static.  You must invoke it on the object passed in from the Android project (e.g., `this.leaderBoard.submitScore(...)`) in your core project.  For first example, see comments at end of wiki the `!` are to be ignored they're HTML problems (yeah, they're confusing).  `ActionResolverAndroid` should not be made abstract -- the other way to fix that is to make sure you implement all methods from the interface --- looks like this (now really confusing) example is botched (`showLongToast` & `showShortToast` vs. `showToast`).

Comment: Thank you. Finally I could compile examples 1 and 2. First example crashes on "startActivity" with null pointer exception. But intent != null. Second examples crashes on runtime with no looper.prepare error. Oh, it seems as a result  I can't add bluetooth support and WEB page opening to my Libgdx game....

Answer (score 3):

You're getting an error because [startActivity()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent%29) is a method in the [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) class.

To be able to use this, your class *must*:

1. Extend Activity or a class that extends Activity
2. Have an Activity instance somewhere, possible passed in through the constructor

In the second case, you'll have something like:

```
public class MyNonActivity {
    Context mContext;
    public MyNonActivity(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    public void myMethod() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, Next.class);
        mContext.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

and to call your class from an [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) or [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) or something else that subclasses [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) or one of its subclasses:

```
MyNonActivity foo = new MyNonActivity(getBaseContext());
```

Make sure you do the above in or after `onCreate()` has been called.

Comment: I do understand that startActivity() is a method in the Activity class. How to run startActivity() anyway - that is a question

Comment: Unfortunately it will be error in MyNonActivity() on "startActivity" line. How to run method in "Next" class? I tryed something like that before. And it is impossible to get context ion non-activity class. It is possible to get in main activity. But maybe it is wrong way. And I got "looper prepare error". I don't know how to struggle with it. All 3 examples that I mentioned above and tryed use interface.